# What is the internal api that can navigate to daygridmonth, timegridweek and timegridday when using a custom button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want. When I click dayGridMonth using customButtons, I hope that the dayGridMonthFunc gets the internal api daygridmonth and clicks it to display the screen as a month.

```
<div>           
 <FullCalendar
                class='bit-calendar'
                :options="config"
                ref="fullCalendar"
                locale=ko
                defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                :header="{
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                }"
                :headerToolbar="{
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                }"
                :customButtons="{ 
                  dayGridMonth: {
                    text: '월',
                    click: this.dayGridMonthFunc
                  },
                  timeGridWeek: {
                    text: '주',
                    click: this.timeGridWeekFunc
                  },
                  timeGridDay: {
                    text: '일',
                    click: this.timeGridDayFunc
                  },                  
                }"
              />
</div>

methods: {
   dayGridMonthFunc(event) {
        console.log(event);
   }
}
```

Comment: ex) It was used as this.$refs.name.getApi() when selecting the button for the next month before the calendar. Like this, I want to know the internal function of the month/week/day button.

Answer (score 0):

The function for selecting a specific view is clearly listed in the fullCalendar documentation already: [ChangeView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView).

---

But you don't need custom buttons for this task! Instead, just change the [locale](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale) to Korean:

```
locale: "ko"
```

Or in the vue-specific syntax:

```
locale="ko"
```

I see you already tried this with `locale=ko` in your code, but I think you need quote marks round the `ko`, and also you need to ensure the additional locale module is loaded.

Here's a working demo using native JS (as I'm not familiar enough with vue): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNZbmRB - as you can see the Korean characters you want for those buttons are displayed by default, without needing to define any custom configuration.

Comment: I am grateful for your question.

I have an issue where the week/month/day does not appear the moment I select the week/month/day using the custom button.

Comment: I didn't ask a question, I provided you a solution. You don't need a custom button, you can uust use the locale correctly instead.  Did you understand what I wrote? Did you view the demo?